# Handle logic in SQL or Frontend

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an order table that contains customer info such as name and current status.

[image: order table]

I also have a fetching table that represents the store associates gathering the products for the order for the reason of tracking how much time is spent gathering items.

[image: fetching table]

Fetching records reference an order and a fetching group. Each order can have multiple fetching groups, is it possible to calculate how long it took to fetch an order with multiple fetching groups in SQL, or is this something I should just handle elsewhere such as the frontend where I want to display OrderId, Status, CustomerName, FetchingDuration (EndProductFetch - StartProductFetch).

Comment: Use a relational database for what it's designed to do: join tables.

Comment: My issue comes when I join and group the fetching table by orderId and fetchingGroup I need to calculate the time difference between the multiple groupings per order and then sum them up to get the total fetching duration which so far hasn't been straightforward.

Comment: Well, show us what you have tried. And show us the expected results from the sample data provided. Also please avoid using images for data - instead use formatted text.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Order
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM Fetching
    WHERE Order.OrderId = Fetching.FetchingId
    Group By Fetching.OrderId, Fetching.FetchingGroup 
) AS Fetching_Duration_Records


Unsure how to take Fetching_Duration_Records and do StartProductFetch - EndProductFetch to give the fetching duration per order. The fetching duration would have to aggregate at the order level. So the information needed from the query would be OrderId, Status, CustomerName, FetchingDuration.

Comment: [Edit] an additional information into the question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Images of data aren't very helpful. Without DDL we are left guessing the data type of the date/times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following to get the total of minutes required for fetching per order:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.Status, o.CustomerName
      ,fo.FetchingDurationMinutes
  FROM Orders o
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT OrderId, SUM(DATE_DIFF(seconds, StartProductFetch, EndProductFetch)/60.0) FetchingDurationMinutes
               FROM Fetching
               GROUP BY OrderId
            ) fo
    ON fo.OrderId = o.OrderId
```

If you want to distinguish the FetchingGroup as well, you can extend the query as follows:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.Status, o.CustomerName
      ,fo.FetchingGroup, fo.FetchingDurationMinutes
  FROM Orders o
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT OrderId, FetchingGroup, SUM(DATE_DIFF(seconds, StartProductFetch, EndProductFetch)/60.0) FetchingDurationMinutes
               FROM Fetching
               GROUP BY OrderId, FetchingGroup
            ) fo
    ON fo.OrderId = o.OrderId
```